# What would be a good code structure for test fields?

Tags: java, arrays, field

I have a test class with fields which contain test content. It looks like:

```
class Test {
  public static String s1 = " ... long string ... ";
  public static String s2 = " ... long string ... ";
  public static String s3 = " ... long string ... ";
}
```

Now I would like to use these fields in a loop, so I wrote an additional array

```
  public static String[] a = {s1, s2, s3};
```

This structure works fine, but is a bit ugly because everytime I add or delete a field, I have do change the array, too.

The only solution to re-structure my code without the manually manipulating of the array is to write it all in the array at once:

```
class Test {
  public static String[] a = {" ... long string ... ", " ... long string ... ",
                              " ... long string ... "};
}
```

As you can see, this makes the code unreadable, especially when we have to deal with > 10 long strings.

What could be a better structure ?

Comment: Why not create a method that reads strings from a given input file? That way all you have to do is feed the test a file to read from and it reads in however many strings are input into the file. Use some character/string to indicate when the string starts/ends such that the code will be able to break them apart

Comment: @TheCapn Good idea, thank you ! I will consider this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use them in a loop, it makes me think that they are homogeneous in some way. Also the variable names (`s1`, `s2`, `s3`) are meaningless as they stand. So go for array (or use `Arrays.asList()` idiom).

If each string has a different meaning and is used separately, definitely have separate variables. If you want to have best of both worlds (separate variables and a list that is easily maintainable, consider this):

```
class Test {
    public static final String s1 = str(" ... long string ... ");
    public static final String s2 = str(" ... long string ... ");
    public static final String s3 = str(" ... long string ... ");

    public static final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String str(String s) {
        strings.add(s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

And last but not least, remember about `final` keyword.

Comment: Great options and explanation. Thank you. The suggested solution with the `str` function is nice.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use an `enum` e.g.

```
public enum Test
{
    S1("... long string 1..."), 

    S2("... long string 2...");

    private String value;

    Test(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

You can then access the instances individually or as a list e.g.:-

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /* Single instance */
    String value1 = Test.S1.getValue();

    /* All instances */
    for (Test test : Test.values())
    {
        System.out.println(test.getValue());
    }
}
```

With this approach you don't have to worry about modifying the array when you add or delete new values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about lists ? If you don't care about the order of your strings, it's a good solution. It's pretty easy to implement, and you can add or delete as many elements as you want.
[Wikipedia - List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28abstract_data_type%29)